# Homepage URL showing a 404 error

Tags: 404-error, homepage

I migrated my website to this new domain. I removed the original homepage and re-labelled the current homepage as home.Now when I visit the homepage, it shows a 404 error although the page exist and also the front page is set as a static page and set to display the correct page.

Comment: Try visiting Settings > Permalinks (you don't have to change anything, just loading that page refreshes permalinks), then clear your browser cache completely or use an incognito window to check if that solved the problem. Right now www.changingliveswellness.ie/home/ resolves to a page - if that should actually be at www.changingliveswellness.ie it looks like WP is not recognizing that it's set to your static front page. I'd check Settings > Reading again and clear any site caches you may have.

Answer (score 0):

*Home*, in your menu, should never point to a physical ( created by you ) page. Its meaning is simple - URL of your domain ( eg. `http://example.com` or `https://example.com` ).

Remove *Home* from your menu. Add *Home* to the menu as ***Custom Link***, with URL = '**/**' and Navigation Label = '**Home**'.

You're saying that your front page is a static page, created by you, with a content. Which means that in *Settings -> Reading -> Front page displays* you've selected *A static page (select below)*, and in dropdown you've selected your existing page. Remove from the menu a link to that page. WordPress will know, based on your settings, what page to display, when a visitor clicks on *Home*.

If you intend to show all posts to your visitors, create a new page with title only ( eg. Posts, Blog ). Publish it. Select this page in dropdown of *Settings -> Reading -> Front page displays -> Posts page*. Add this page to your menu.

That's all. Now trash your Home page, created by you.

Comment: wtf are you talking about dude? Everyone’s home page is crafted. At least it should be somehow.  This is the opposite of all thing.